# rendering is happpening before a function is executed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

page is getting loaded before i check for exists function..how to handle it

```
   let messag="";
   console.log(req.query.id);
     idpassmodel.exists({name:req.query.id}, function(err,result){
            if(result===true){
                console.log("before");
                messag="id already exists";
                if(req.query.pass!==req.query.pass1){
                    messag="passwords dont match";
                }
            }
        
    });
    console.log("after");
    res.render('signup',{message:messag});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens so because the `exists` call works `async` so I suggest to move the `render` call into a callback.

```
 let message="";
 console.log(req.query.id);
 idpassmodel.exists({name:req.query.id}, function(err,result){
        if (result===true) {
            console.log("before");
            message = "id already exists";
            if (req.query.pass!==req.query.pass1) {
                message = "passwords dont match";
            }
        }
        res.render('signup',{message:message});
});
console.log("after");
```

I also renamed your variable `messag` to `message`.